# Chat: following conversations that are not 'linked'

Tags: feature-request

In the chat rooms, you can reply to messages by clicking the `newreply` link ("link my next chat message as a reply to this"). Likewise, you can see follow linked messages by clicking the `reply-info` link ("This is a reply to an earlier message").

However, it is difficult to follow `@` replies if the messages are **not** linked. Is there way to do this using the **search** or does such a feature not exist?

Answer (score 4):

The feature doesn't exist, but it also doesn't make sense. If you're replying to someone, you use a direct reply (`:message-id You're totally right!`), and your reply will be linked to their message. If you're just trying to send them a message, you use a ping (`@SomeUser You're my best friend (hug)`). Chat alerts them, but doesn't link your message to a previous message, because you weren't trying to reply to a message

Comment: Technically speaking, I've noticed that chat always highlights that person's last message. The messages may not be linked per se, but the highlighting behavior is the same.

Comment: @Chris that's correct, if you use `@<username>` it will just highlight the user's last message.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Well, it kind of goes against my argument that you use `@username` if you don't want to connect your message to their last message. I don't know why it does that

Comment: No, I was just trying to clarify Michael. Maybe I was unclear. **You are correct:** If you use the `@<username` syntax then **your message *will not* be linked to any other chat message.** Chat *will* highlight that person's last message as a convience. But your message will **not** be actually linked to it.